# incorrect number representation in oracle json generation method

Tags: json, oracle

the query below returns {"value":.0133} rather than {"value":0.0133} i.e. Oracle returns data in LAX format. Is it a way how to return 0.0133 without explicit to_char?

```
select json_object(  'value' is 0.0133 format json strict) o from dual t
```